# LINQ grouping multiple fields only if one of the fields is a specific value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am trying to group a list by 2 fields (Category, then Vendor), but at different values. If the category is "01", sum all the cost. If the category is not "01", group by the category, and then by the vendor.

Some demo data:

```
List<MyItem> myItemList = new List<MyItem>();
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven1", Cost=100, Category="01"});
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven2", Cost=10, Category="02"});
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven3", Cost=50, Category="02"}));
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven2", Cost=40, Category="01"});
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven2", Cost=20, Category="01"});
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven3", Cost=30, Category="02"});
myItemList.Add(new MyItem{Vendor="Ven1", Cost=10, Category="03"});
```

What I currently am doing:

```
List<MyItem> groupedItems = myItemList.GroupBy(a=> new {a.Category, a.Vendor})
                                      .Select(b=> new MyItem{
                                            Vendor = b.First().Vendor,
                                            Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
                                            Category = b.First().Category
                                       }).ToList();
```

What I am trying to do (aka my best guess):

```
List<MyItem> groupedItems = myItemList.GroupBy(a=> new {a.Category.Where(z=>z.Category.Equals("01:)), a.Vendor})
                                      .Select(b=> new MyItem{
                                            Vendor = b.First().Vendor,
                                            Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
                                            Category = b.First().Category
                                       }).ToList();
```

Desired Result:

```
Category = "01", Vendor = "N/A ", Cost = 160
Category = "02", Vendor = "Ven2", Cost = 10
Category = "02", Vendor = "Ven3", Cost = 80
Category = "03", Vendor = "Ven1", Cost = 10
```

Comment: So basically you want to group all the 01 categories reguardless of Vendor and then everything else is grouped on category and vendor?  Could you show the desired results for your example data?

Comment: Why is your cost string?

Comment: You could handle these cases separately and then combine the results. First use a Where to get only the items in 01 category and then the rest.

Comment: @S.Petrosov it isn't just a bad example. I'll fix it.

Comment: @juharr The bottom list, labeled Desired Result is what I would like

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa was seeing if there was a cleaner way than doing this, I wanted to keep it all together. If it is not possible, then I will go this route.

Comment: I think this will be more difficult to do in one LINQ query than divide into parts

Comment: @S.Petrosov I think you are right, as that is what I ended up doing. I'll add it as an answer unless someone who is a linq expert knows how to do it in one query.

Comment: @MichaelGulik and one thing more, in your example you have sum Costs for Category "02" but should it be so?

Comment: @S.Petrosov correct, as I am then grouping by category, by vendor if it is not category "01". Else, if it were category "01", group by category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GroupBy` returns an anonymous type with 2 fields. The values inside the returned object can be anything. In this case they can be altered if the category is "01": `myItemList.GroupBy(a=> new {a.Category, Vendor= a.Category == "01" ? null : a.Vendor})` To keep in line with your current code, the property is named Vendor, but can be any name.

In your current code:

```
List<MyItem> groupedItems = myItemList
    .GroupBy(a => new {a.Category, Vendor = a.Category == "01" ? null : a.Vendor})
    .Select(b => new MyItem
    {
        Vendor = b.First().Vendor,
        Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
        Category = b.First().Category
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or with a slight alteration, instead of the `First()` value of a group, you can reuse the key (and implement the `N\A` in one go)

```
List<MyItem> groupedItems = myItemList
      .GroupBy(a=> new {a.Category, Vendor= a.Category == "01" ? "N/A" : a.Vendor})
      .Select(b=> new MyItem{
            Vendor = b.Key.Vendor,
            Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
            Category = b.Key.Category
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Or possibly `Vendor = b.First().Category == "01" ? "N\A" : b.First().Vendor,`

Comment: @RufusL Thanks, Missed the 'N/A' wish in the desired result. Added an option for that, only by reusing the key rather than repeating the logic.

Comment: Now, lets say I would have to only preform grouping if the Category is "01", and everything else is ungrouped, how does that work using this?

Comment: Do you mean "01" is a group and everything else is a group? `.GroupBy(a=> a.Category == "01" ? "1" : null)`  (or fill the key with whatever values should be used for Vendor and such)

Comment: 01 is going to be grouped, everything else is left ungrouped

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I went with the idea of creating two separate queries:

```
List<MyItem> groupedItemsByCat01 = myItemList.Where(z => z.Category.Equals("01"))
                                             .GroupBy(a => a.Category)
                                             .Select(b=> new MyItem{
                                                Vendor = "N/A",
                                                Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
                                                Category = b.First().Category
                                           }).ToList();

List<MyItem> groupedItemsByOther = myItemList.Where(z => !z.Category.Equals("01"))
                                             .GroupBy(a => new {a.Category, a.Vendor})
                                             .Select(b=> new MyItem{
                                                Vendor = b.First().Vendor,
                                                Cost = b.Sum(c => c.Cost),
                                                Category = b.First().Category
                                             }).ToList();

List<MyItem> final = new List<MyItem>();
final.AddRange(groupedItemsByCat01);
final.AddRange(groupedItemsByOther);
```

Comment: For `Category.Equals("01")`, the `Vendor` should be `"N\A"`

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit tricky to do that in one Linq-Expression:

```
var newList = myItemList
    .Where(item => item.Category != "01")
    .GroupBy(item => new {item.Category, item.Vendor})
    .Select(group => new MyItem()
    {
        Vendor = group.Key.Vendor,
        Category = group.Key.Category,
        Cost = group.Sum(item => item.Cost)
    })
    .Union(new[]
    {
        new MyItem()
        {
            Vendor = "N/A",
            Category = "01",
            Cost = myItemList.Where(item => item.Category == "01").Sum(item => item.Cost)
        }
    });

foreach (var loItem in newList)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Category = {0}, Vendor = {1}, Cost = {2}", 
        loItem.Category, loItem.Vendor, loItem.Cost);
}
```