# LINQ group a list and exclude groups that contain a record with a field value

Tags: c#, linq, filter, lambda, grouping

Having trouble setting up my lamda to exlude groups with a record that has a field with a value. My data example:

```
CTY ProcId ProcTyp ProcDate
ZZZ 23-015 INIT    2023-01-26T20:04:30
ZZZ 23-015 UPDATE  2023-01-26T20:04:45
ZZZ 23-015 UPLOAD  2023-01-26T20:05:00
ZZZ 23-015 UPLOAD  2023-05-31T15:12:01
ZZZ 23-015 DELETE  2023-07-25T12:28:38

ZZZ 23-246 INIT    2023-11-07T23:31:09
ZZZ 23-246 DELETE  2023-11-08T16:49:55

ZZZ 23-248 INIT    2023-11-08T16:40:18
ZZZ 23-248 UPDATE  2023-11-08T16:43:14
ZZZ 23-248 UPLOAD  2023-11-08T16:43:35
```

What I'm looking to do is to group the data by CTY and then ProcId and then get the MAX ProcDate. However, those groups that have 1 or more ProcTyp = 'DELETE' must be omitted from the grouping. I dont just want to filter out those records but filter out the GROUPS that have those records. In this case the result should be a list:

```
CTY ProcId ProcTyp MaxProcDate 
ZZZ 23-248 UPLOAD  2023-11-08T16:43:35
```

My current code in C#:

```
var resListMax = resListAll
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.CTY, c.ProcId})
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.CTY,
                    g.Key.ProcId,
                    MaxProcDate = g.Max(row => row.ProcDate),
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.CTY).ThenBy(x => x.ProcId)
                .ToList();
```

I have been looking at examples but just not getting where I should put the group filtering? I feel like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915994/linq-grouping-multiple-fields-only-if-one-of-the-fields-is-a-specific-value) is what I want but not sure how to implement. Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you go a g.sum as a column in the select where proctype is delete and then after the select you could do a where on the new column's value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you post an example for me to learn from please.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I think i see where you are going with this. Please take a look at my edits and see what you think.

Comment: Sounds like you found the answer. But it should be `x.ProcTyp == "DELETE"` based on your data. And I would suggest using `x.NumDeletes == 0` as it is not possible to result in a negative value when `Count`. Next, please post it as answer post instead of in the question and mark it as answer once available.

Comment: Or alternative way is replacing the `NumDelete` to return the boolean with `HasDelete = g.Any(x => x.ProcTyp == "DELETE")` and in your Where clause to filter with boolean: `.Where(x => !HasDelete)`

Comment: I think this can be best done most concisely by adding `.Where(g => !g.Any(x => x.ProcTyp == "XWT.DELETE"))` immediately after the `.GroupBy()`. If the group contains *any* deletes, the where-condition is false and that group is dropped.

Comment: @TN, better create answer.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for the insight everyone. Let me add the answer and edit my original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `.Where()` filter immediately after the `.GroupBy()` that checks for and excludes groups containing *any* "deleted" member.

```
var resListMax = resListAll
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.CTY, c.ProcId})
                .Where(g => !g.Any(x => x.ProcTyp == "XWT.DELETE"))
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.CTY,
                    g.Key.ProcId,
                    MaxProcDate = g.Max(row => row.ProcDate),
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.CTY).ThenBy(x => x.ProcId)
                .ToList();
```

The logic actually reads "include only those groups that do *not* have any deleted members".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I decided to go with this version since its a bit easier for me to read and to maintain.

```
var resListMax = resListAll
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.CTY, c.ProcId})
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.CTY,
                    g.Key.ProcId,
                    MaxProcDate = g.Max(row => row.ProcDate),      // get the max time stamp in the group
                    HasDeletes = g.Any(x => x.ProcTyp == "DELETE") // gets a flag for any deletes in the group
                })
                .Where(x => !x.HasDeletes) // only include those groups without any deletes
                .OrderBy(x => x.CTY).ThenBy(x => x.ProcId)
                .ToList();
```